# What's more idiomatic in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing the data structures for my program (a toy compiler), and I'm trying to understand what's the best way to define the AST:

Current code

```
data RExpr = RExpr Location InnerRExpr
data InnerRExpr = RLExpr LExpr | RConstant Constant | RMathExpr MathExpr | FCall Id [RExpr]
```

Alternative A

```
data RExpr = RLExpr Location LExpr
           | RConstant Location Constant
           | RMathExpr Location MathExpr
           | FCall Location Id [RExpr]
```

Alternative B

```
data RExpr = RLExpr { loc::Location, getLexpr::LExpr}
           | RConstant { loc::Location, getConstant::Constant}
           | RMathExpr { loc::Location, getExpr::MathExpr}
           | FCall { loc::Location, id::Id, params::[RExpr] }
```

Honestly I'm not satisfied with either of the three options, because the current code means that I have an extraneous object in the AST which doesn't really mean anything, alternative A means that I have to pattern match every time I want to extract the location (or write a boilerplate function that does it) and alternative B means cluttering the global namespace with functions whose names are likely to collide.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tend towards the former, and then use a lens or traversal to extract the location.

```
import Control.Lens

class HasLocation t where
  loc :: Lens' t Location

instance HasLocation RExpr where
  loc f (RLExpr l e)    = f l <&> \l' -> RLExpr l' e
  loc f (RConstant l c) = f l <&> \l' -> RConstant l' c
  loc f (RMathExpr l m) = f l <&> \l' -> RMathExpr l' m
  loc f (FCall l i xs) = f l <&> \l' -> FCall l' i xs
```

With the `class` you can overload the use of `loc` for other data types. Because it is a lens you can use it to get/set/modify the location with a large vocabulary without cluttering your namespace.

Comment: `Control.Lens`... never heard of it. I'll look it up, thanks

Comment: I *knew* I was reinventing the wheel! I had a (specialization of) lenses in my code already. Cleaning up and using lenses, thank you very much